# jquery .load() and wordpress usability

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on wordpress theme, you can take a look at: greenzoner.pl. What I want to do is showing all posts usability in the middle div, i.e single posts, comments, attached pictures etc. 2 side divs should never reload. I am open to any alternatives to method I try to use (maybe IFRAME?).

To load sigle post I used jquery .load()

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$(".openpost, .comments-link").click(function() {
    var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".container").load(post_url);
    return false;   
});

$(".closepost").click(function() {
    $(".container").load(index.php .postlist);
    return false;
});
```

I've encountered a major problem - I cant use ajax comments ( i tried many plugins, tutorials, etc, nothing works) - so basicly when you post reply, you get redirected to eg. http://greenzoner.pl/?p=32#comment-26. My current js for comments is:

```
var commentform = $('#commentform'); // find the comment form
commentform.prepend('<div id="comment-status" ></div>'); // add info panel before the form to provide feedback or errors

var statusdiv = $('#comment-status'); // define the infopanel

commentform.submit(function(){
    //serialize and store form data in a variable
    var formdata = commentform.serialize();

    //Add a status message
    statusdiv.html('<p>Processing...</p>');

    //Extract action URL from commentform
    var formurl = commentform.attr('action');

    //Post Form with data
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: formurl,
        data: formdata,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            statusdiv.html('<p class="wdpajax-error" >You might have left one of the fields blank, or be posting too quickly</p>');
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            if (data == "success")
                statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Thanks for your comment. We appreciate your response.</p>');
            else
                statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >Please wait a while before posting your next comment</p>');

            commentform.find('textarea[name=comment]').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

and php:

```
add_action('comment_post', 'ajaxify_comments',20, 2);
function ajaxify_comments($comment_ID, $comment_status) {
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&      strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
        //If AJAX Request Then
        switch($comment_status){
            case '0':
                //notify moderator of unapproved comment
                wp_notify_moderator($comment_ID);
            case '1': //Approved comment
                echo "success";
                $commentdata = &get_comment($comment_ID, ARRAY_A);
                $post = &get_post($commentdata['comment_post_ID']); 
                wp_notify_postauthor($comment_ID, $commentdata['comment_type']);
                break;
                default:
                echo "error";
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

Other problem with using this method, is post linking.

Comment: I'm not helping but: if you wanna talk about usability you shouldn't even think about Iframes.

Comment: I'll second janw's comment on iframes.  It's worth repeating:  Don't do it unless you absolutely have to.